# ComplexProperties with Reflections

Tags: c#, reflection

I have used reflection for divide the complex property. For example, if I bind `A.B[0]`, CustomerName means CustomerName is returned. Can anyone help to reduce the code?

```
var itemproperties = view.GetItemProperties();                

if (itemproperties != null)
{
    if (propName.Contains("."))
    {
        string actualproperty = propName;
        string[] propertyNameList = propName.Split('.');
        int complexPropertyCount = propertyNameList.Count(), index = 0;
        bool isArrayproperty = actualproperty.IndexOf('[') != -1;

        if (isArrayproperty)
        {
            string strindex = actualproperty.Substring(actualproperty.IndexOf('[') + 1, actualproperty.IndexOf(']') - actualproperty.IndexOf('[') - 1);
            index = Convert.ToInt32(strindex);
            string property = actualproperty.Substring(0, actualproperty.IndexOf('['));
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyNameList.Length; i++)
            {
                if (propertyNameList[i].Contains('['))
                {
                    if (property.Contains("."))
                        property = propertyNameList[i].Substring(0, propertyNameList[i].IndexOf('['));
                    propertyNameList[i] = property;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < complexPropertyCount - 1; iterator++)
        {
            var tempProperyDescriptor = itemproperties.Find(propertyNameList[iterator], true);
            if (tempProperyDescriptor != null)       // Fix for SD 8318
            {
                record = tempProperyDescriptor.GetValue(record);
                itemproperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(record);
            }
        }

        actualproperty = propertyNameList[complexPropertyCount - 1];

        if (isArrayproperty)
        {
            IList arrayList = ((IEnumerable)record) as IList;

            foreach (var item in arrayList)
            {
                var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(actualproperty);

                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    return null;
                if (arrayList.IndexOf(item) == index)
                {
                    return propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        var propertyinfo = record.GetType().GetProperty(actualproperty);

        if (propertyinfo == null && view is CollectionViewAdv)
        {
            var sourceType = (view as CollectionViewAdv).SourceType;
            if (sourceType != null && typeof(ICustomTypeDescriptor).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
                return itemproperties.Find(actualproperty, true).GetValue(record);
            return null;
        }

        if (!itemaccessor.ContainsKey(propName))
        {
            PropertyAccessor accessor = new PropertyAccessor(propertyinfo);
            itemaccessor.Add(propName, accessor);
            var val = accessor.GetValue(record);
            return val;
        }
    }

    if (record == null)
        return null;
    return itemaccessor[propName].GetValue(record);
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you simply return `null` if the `itemproperties` are `null`, do that immediately:

```
if (itemproperties == null)
{
    return null;
}

if (propName.Contains("."))
{
}
```

That way you don't need to have 80+ lines inside an `if`.

The same is probably true for your next check -- `if (propName.Contains("."))` -- but since you don't provide us with enough information I cannot help you there: where does `propName` come from? Where does `record` come from?

I see duplicate code:

```
actualproperty.Substring(0, actualproperty.IndexOf('['));
propertyNameList[i].Substring(0, propertyNameList[i].IndexOf('['));
```

Shouldn't that be converted to a method call?

Comment: Hi, in this propName is A.B[0].Value and the record is data which i have.

Answer (score 1):

**Code flow**

The code flow is really confusing. You are checking for `isArrayproperty` then proceed without the need of `isArrayproperty` then again checking `isArrayproperty`.

This is a strong indicator that **this method is doing to much**. It should be at least splitted into 2 methods. One method for processing an `ArrayProperty` and one for a default property.

By using guard conditions like **@BCdotNET** suggested you can reduce horizontal spacing.

So instead of

> ```
> if (itemproperties != null)
> {
>     if (propName.Contains("."))
>     {
> ```

you can use

```
if (itemproperties == null) { return null; }
if (!propertyName.Contains("."))
{
    return (record != null) ? itemaccessor[propertyName].GetValue(record) : null;
}
```

This

> ```
> IList arrayList = ((IEnumerable)record) as IList;
>
> foreach (var item in arrayList)
> {
>     var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
>
>     if (propertyInfo == null)
>         return null;
>     if (arrayList.IndexOf(item) == index)
>     {
>         return propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
>     }
> }
> ```

could be simplified to

```
IList arrayList = ((IEnumerable)record) as IList;
if (arrayList.Count <= index) { return null; }

var item = arrayList[index];
var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

return propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
```

**Codeduplication**

You are awful often calling `actualproperty.IndexOf('[')`, exactly 4 times. Do you think the value could magically change ?

Declare a variable which holds the value.

**General**

Declaring multiple variables on the same line removes readability of the code. Especially if the first variable is initialized by calling a method.

> ```
> int complexPropertyCount = propertyNameList.Count(), index = 0;
> ```

This should be better written like

```
int complexPropertyCount = propertyNameList.Count();
int index = 0;
```

Why do you use the extension method `Count()` instead of the `Length` property ?

**Style**

You should always be consistent with your code style. Sometimes you are using braces `{}` for single `if` statements, sometimes not. In my opinion you should use them always, but that is a matter of taste.

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) variable names should be named using `camelCase` casing. So e.g `propertyinfo` should be `propertyInfo`.

**Refactoring**

Taken the above into account your former code should be reduced to

```
if (itemproperties == null) { return null; }
if (!propertyName.Contains("."))
{
    return (record != null) ? itemaccessor[propertyName].GetValue(record) : null;
}

bool isArrayProperty = propertyName.IndexOf('[') != -1;

if (isArrayProperty)
{
    return GetArrayValue(view, propertyName, record);
}
else
{
    return GetDefaultValue(view, propertyName, record);
}
```

where `GetArrayValue()` is simplified to

```
private object GetArrayValue(object view, String propertyName, object record)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection itemProperties = view.GetItemProperties();

    int index = GetIndexValue(propertyName);
    string[] propertyNameList = GetArrayPropertyNames(propertyName);

    Tuple<object, PropertyDescriptorCollection> tuple = DoSomething(record, propertyNameList, itemProperties);
    record = tuple.Item1;
    itemProperties = tuple.Item2;

    propertyName = propertyNameList[propertyNameList.Length - 1];

    IList arrayList = ((IEnumerable)record) as IList;

    if (arrayList.Count <= index) { return null; }

    object item = arrayList[index];
    var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

     return propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
}
```

by extracting

```
private int GetIndexValue(String propertyName)
{
    int openBracketIndex = propertyName.IndexOf('[');
    int closeBracketIndex = propertyName.IndexOf(']');

    string strindex = propertyName.Substring(openBracketIndex + 1, closeBracketIndex - openBracketIndex - 1);
    return Convert.ToInt32(strindex);
}
private String[] GetArrayPropertyNames(String propertyName)
{
    string[] propertyNameList = propertyName.Split('.');

    int openBracketIndex = propertyName.IndexOf('[');
    string property = propertyName.Substring(0, openBracketIndex);

    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNameList.Length; i++)
    {
        openBracketIndex = propertyNameList[i].IndexOf('[');
        if (openBracketIndex > -1)
        {
            if (property.Contains("."))
            {
                property = propertyNameList[i].Substring(0, openBracketIndex);
            }
            propertyNameList[i] = property;
            break;
        }
    }

    return propertyNameList;
}
```

and the `DoSomething()` method (please change it to a meaningful name yourself)

```
private Tuple<object, PropertyDescriptorCollection> DoSomething(object record, String[] propertyNameList, PropertyDescriptorCollection itemProperties)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNameList.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var propertyDescriptor = itemProperties.Find(propertyNameList[i], true);
        if (propertyDescriptor != null)
        {
            record = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(record);
            itemProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(record);
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<object, PropertyDescriptorCollection>(record, itemProperties);
}
```

which is also used by the `GetDefaultValue()` method

```
private object GetDefaultValue(object view, String propertyName, object record)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection itemProperties = view.GetItemProperties();
    string[] propertyNameList = propertyName.Split('.');

    Tuple<object, PropertyDescriptorCollection> tuple = DoSomething(record, propertyNameList, itemProperties);
    record = tuple.Item1;
    itemProperties = tuple.Item2;

    String actualproperty = propertyNameList[propertyNameList.Length - 1];

    var propertyinfo = record.GetType().GetProperty(actualproperty);

    if (propertyinfo == null && view is CollectionViewAdv)
    {
        var sourceType = (view as CollectionViewAdv).SourceType;
        if (sourceType != null && typeof(ICustomTypeDescriptor).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
        {
            return itemProperties.Find(actualproperty, true).GetValue(record);
        }
        return null;
    }

    if (!itemaccessor.ContainsKey(propertyName))
    {
        PropertyAccessor accessor = new PropertyAccessor(propertyinfo);
        itemaccessor.Add(propertyName, accessor);
        return accessor.GetValue(record);
    }

    if (record == null) { return null; }

    return itemaccessor[propertyName].GetValue(record);
}
```